# cannot copy string to an character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, setter

```
#include<iostream>
class ravi
{
    private:
        char a[10],char b[10];
public:
    void setdata(char x[10],char y[10])
    {
        a = x; b = y;
    }
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << a << b;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ravi r;
    r.setdata("text","copied");
    r.show();
}
```

i am trying to copy the strings "text" "copied" to x and y and  i am getting an error that "incompatible types in assignment from char* to char" .can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Strings in C++ are `std::string`. You are using char arrays, aka C-strings, NUL terminated strings, etc.

Comment: That's not how C strings work. Try using `std::string` and save yourself from the hassle.

Comment: use `std::string a, b;` instead of `char a[10], b[10];` and change `setdata` to `void setdata(const std::string& x, const std::string& y)`. Don't forget to `#include <string>`. That's a lot better way of doing it than using C strings.

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is?

Answer (score 7):

Strings in C++ are [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You are using char arrays, aka C-strings, NUL terminated strings, etc. which are harder to manipulate.

Simply by replacing the type of `a` and `b` (and a minor improvement on the arguments of `setdata`, you get something working, plus some useful features of `string`:

```
#include <string>
class ravi
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
public:
    void setdata(const char* x, const char* y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }

    void show()
    {
        std::cout << a << b;
    }
};
```

---

If this is possible (regarding the API of `ravi`), try and use `std::string const&` in lieu of `const char*`:

```
void setdata(std::string const& x, std::string const& y)
```

---

With C++17, you'd better use [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) in lieu of `const char*` for argument types:

```
void setdata(std::string_view x, std::string_view y)
```

Comment: Didn't always think much of string view, but you gotta love the fact that it now takes only one function to accept all variants plain char strings, without forcing the caller into using `c_str` or allocating or what not.

Comment: @StoryTeller if I'm not mistaken `const std::string&` would also accept all of them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Everyone "without [...] allocating or what not" Passing a `char*` etc. to a `string` constructor would construct a `string` from it, which (barring the optimisation of SSO) would mean allocating, just to get something that will only last for a single call anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d so technically it does the job, but takes more space and cycles (for strings larger than SSO's ability) to do so. Anyway, thanks for the tip, i'll use `std::string_view` from now on.

Comment: @YSC "Strings in C++ are std::string." It is totally wrong statement.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ho come on! OP is a beginner. How would you state it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It may be incorrect (technically), but it is totally the right statement here.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. So these statements

```
a=x;b=y;
```

are invalid.

You should use standard C function `strcpy` or `strncpy` declared in the header `<cstring>` to copy character arrays. Also string literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So the parameters of the member function `setdata` should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

```
void setdata( const char x[], const char y[] )
{
    strncpy( a, x, sizeof( a ) );
    a[sizeof( a ) - 1] = '\0';

    strncpy( b, x, sizeof( b ) );
    b[sizeof( b ) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Take into account that this statement is invalid

```
char a[10],char b[10];
```

Either you should write

```
char a[10]; char b[10];
```

or

```
char a[10], b[10];
```

Comment: how to eleminate this warn : ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: Please recommend the secure functions instead of the ones that only exist for backward compatibility

Comment: Note: since `snprintf` is guaranteed to put a final `'\0'` in `dest`, I tend to write `snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%s", source)`.

Comment: "Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator." `std::array` does, and that's one of the various reasons that it's often better than a plain array. Not that this alone would solve the problems with the OP's assumptions.

Comment: @Roushan I wrote in my answer that the parameters should be defined with the qualifier const. String literals have types of constant character arrays.

Comment: @underscore_d std::array is not an array. It is a user-defined container.

Comment: "Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator." didnt they decay to pointers when they reach that statement?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In fact, I didn't say it was an array. But either way, it is obvious why I said what I did, as that user-defined container is written to be *thought of* as an array for many purposes, and the pedantry is not useful.

Comment: @user463035818 It is evident that the author of the question means assignment.  And array designators are converted to rvalues. So again you may not use the assignment operator with arrays.

Comment: @underscore_d You only confuse readers with your irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strcpy` function from `string.h`:

```
#include <string.h>

void setdata(char x[10],char y[10])
{
    strcpy(a,x);
    strcpy(b,y);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `strcpy_s`? `strcpy` should not be used anymore... It would also be nice if you explained why what he's doing isn't working.

Comment: A better solution is to replace character arrays with `std::string`.